# Perform a line break after the white space in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have the following variable:

```
var profile_age = "4 months"
```

and perform this in my js:

```
$('.profile_age').html(profile_age);
```

to render the text here:

```
<p class="profile_age"></p>
```

Is there any way to render it as `4<br>months` so there is a line break between the two words?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try replacing the space with `<br>`

```
profile_age = profile_age.replace(' ', '<br>');
```

Comment: This will replace only the first occurrence of the space.

Answer (score -1):

Use \n to break line or to print in new line

```
profile_age = profile_age.replace(' ', '\n');
```

Comment: OP clearly mentioned that the space(s) are to be replaced by `<br>`. `\n` doesn't make any difference in HTML.

Comment: Depends how you bind that veriable.

Comment: Could you clarify, how binding the variable will change the behaviour?